# Rails Routing :on => :collection failing, but only sometimes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

Some details, I'm using Rails 3.2.1 on Ruby 1.8.7/WEBrick locally and 1.8.7 EE/Passenger on a server)

Here's my issue, I have a controller named foo with an action named bar, and I need to create a route to it.  "bar" is accessed via get.

So like all the docs say, I do:

```
resources :foo do
  get :bar, :on => :collection
end
```

When I load up the view (in haml) that has:
    = link_to "Bar", bar_foo_path
, I get:

```
undefined local variable or method `bar_foo_path'
```

Even though it makes no sense, I decided to switch 
    :collection
to
    :member
which will actually allow the page to load, but obviously the link blows up because I don't have any
    :id
to add in the URL.

But here's the odd part, if I then switch
    :member
back to
    :collection
it works as it should...that is until I need to restart the web server, then it's back to broken again.  Locally, this is all the time, so it makes working with these routes frustrating as you can imagine.  It also breaks on the server because I obviously don't have the ability to flip between 
    :member 
and 
    :collection

I can duplicate this on demand both locally and on a server and all that really matters seems to be the move from
    :member
to
    :collection
(so I can start with 
    :member and duplicate the issue)
, so please tell me I'm just doing something stupid, or have I uncovered some sort of bug with
:on => :collection
?

edit:

Just for some clarification, the same behavior is also exhibited if I switch it to the longer form:

```
resources :foo do
  collection do
    get 'bar'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out I should have paid a bit more attention to "rake routes".  For some reason, even though all the documentation says the route should be "bar_foo_path", rails thought it was "bar_foo_index_path".

This doesn't explain why flipping it to
    :member
and then back again to
    :collection
would flip the route to the expected "bar_foo_path" though, but at least the application runs.